# Uncheck first filter after click in second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am doing a table, with two filters checkbox. First is "360" - when you click it in table shows only 360, the same works filter "2D" - when you click it in table shows only 2D. I do this in JS, but what i want to do is when you click "360", in table shows only 360, but when you click "2D" at this time "360" is uncheck. I try to do this by radio button, but then my css checkbox don't works.

JSON "datas":

```
[{"type":"2D"},{"type":"2D"},{"type":"360"},{"type":"2D"},{"type":"360"},{"type":"2D"},{"type":"360"},{"type":"2D"},{"type":"360"},{"type":"2D"}]
```

My Html:

```
        <div class="form-group" style="display:block;width:40px;padding-left: 5px;float:left;height:70px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id='checkbox-360' class='tags-checkbox sr-only' value="" ng-model="type2.type360"><label for='checkbox-360'>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked' style="color:darkgrey;width:2px;font-size:25px;"></i>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-check' style="color:cornflowerblue;width:2px;font-size:25px;"></i>
            <h4><small>360</small></h4>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="display:block;width:40px;padding-left:5px;float:left;height:70px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id='checkbox-20' class='tags-checkbox sr-only' value="" ng-model="type1.type2D"><label for='checkbox-20'>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked' style="color:darkgrey;width:2px;font-size:25px;"></i>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-check' style="color:cornflowerblue;width:2px;font-size:25px;"></i>
            <h4><small>2D</small></h4>
        </label>
        </div>

    <tr ng-repeat="data in datas |TypeFilter360:type2.type360 | TypeFilter2D:type1.type2D>
                    <td>{{data.type}}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS :

```
input[type='checkbox'].tags-checkbox:checked + label > i:first-of-type,
input[type='checkbox'].tags-checkbox + label > i:last-of-type{
    display: none;
}
input[type='checkbox'].tags-checkbox:checked + label > i:last-of-type{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        this.getDatas = function () {
            var datas = $http.get('datas.json', {cache: false});
            return $q.all({datas});
        };
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {

            var promise = service.getDatas();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
            })
})
    .filter('TypeFilter2D', function(){
            return function(data, type2D){
                if (!type2D) return data;
                var filtered2D = [];
                angular.forEach(data, function(item){
                    if(type2D == false) {
                        filtered2D.push(item);
                    }
                    else if(type2D == true && item.type == "2D"){
                        filtered2D.push(item);
                    }
                });

                return filtered2D;
            };
        })
        .filter('TypeFilter360', function(){
            return function(data, type360){
                if (!type360) return data;
                var filtered360 = [];
                angular.forEach(data, function(item){
                    if(type360 == false) {
                        filtered360.push(item);
                    }
                    else if(type360 == true && item.type == "360"){
                        filtered360.push(item);
                    }
                });

                return filtered360;
            };
        })
```

Well what i want to do - when "360" filter is clicked, and then i click "2D" filter "360" should uncheck.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That behavior can actually be defined in your HTML using:

```
<input type="radio" name="filterOptions" id="checkbox-360" ... />
...
<input type="radio" name="filterOptions" id="checkbox-20" ... />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio